# Place order button in Magento 2 checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, payment-methods

I am using Check / Money Order payment method in my website.

I want to change the text of "Place Order" button on the checkout page.

[image]

I tried to change the following file:

**vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/checkmo.html**

but nothing is changing on frontend.

Actually I want to override this template into my own module but it is unable to change anything even changing directly to above file location.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I want to rename the place order text for particular cash on delivery payment method.

Answer (score 2):

**Why you try to do this way for changing text?**

You can do this simply by translation.

Create a **i18n/en_US.csv** inside your theme

**OR**

Inside your module create **i18n/en_US.csv**, In that case make sure your module load after Magento_Checkout module. So module.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Your csv content should be

```
"Place Order","Do you like Place Order?"
```

Clear all cache.

Comment: Actually I want to disable "Place order" button and want to put "Next" button. Can you tell me how to override place order button with "Next" button?

Comment: have you done this @ArshadHussain ?